# Block the Html Navigation in UIWebview

Tags: objective-c, ios

Can Someone Tell me how to use the Api with an Working Example.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request      navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType.
```

Comment: Have you done any research for this question at all, starting with Apple's own documentation?

Comment: yes , but its little confusing to how to use it .

Comment: I'm one of those -1 votes; I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the string version of the URL contained in `request.URL.absoluteString` and if that corresponds to a site you consider permissible for the user to go to, return `YES`, otherwise return `NO`. Or you can look at `request.URL.host` and if it's a domain you consider permissible, again, return `YES`, otherwise `NO`.

For example:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request      navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([request.URL.host isEqualToString:@"www.mysite.com"])
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Make sure to set the delegate for your web view, e.g.:

```
self.webView.delegate = self;
```

And likewise, make sure you define your view controller to conform to `UIWebViewDelegate`, e.g.:

```
@interface ViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

If you google `"shouldStartLoadWithRequest example"`, you'll see tons of examples. Then, go back and review the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a) and reconcile what you see online with the documentation. You really need to get your arms around the Apple documentation if you're going to make much progress writing iOS programs.